# Importing GameKit gives "Ambiguous use of subscript" error

Tags: swift

I'm integrating Game Center into an iOS app and whenever I try and import GameKit the following line of code gives me an "Ambiguous use of subscript" error. The following line of code is trying to read two levels into a JSON and get the value from the key "picID":

```
let facebookIDtown = snapshot.value!["ruler"]!!["picID"] as! String
```

I'm pretty sure its just something that can be fixed if the syntax is adjusted, but I haven't been able to find anything with double exclamation marks online to try and figure it out from that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The compiler – as well as any reader of your question – has no idea what the actual type of the value for key `ruler` is because the returned type is the very common  `AnyObject`.

The human reader can assume that it seems to be another dictionary so you can help the compiler by casting down the type

```
let ruler = snapshot.value!["ruler"] as! [String:AnyObject]
let facebookIDtown = ruler["picID"] as! String
```